# Is this the proper way to delete a linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am learning C and getting used to pointers. I was wondering for a simple linked list structure, is this the proper way to delete a list? I was told you have to take care of everything manually (I'm more of a Java guy, but trying to convert). What suggestions or constructive criticism is there for this? Thanks in advance.

```
/*   assume a struct with: int data; node *next; 
 *   and a global variable node *root; */
void delete_list() {
    if(root==NULL)return;
    node *temp = root;
    while(root!=NULL) {
        temp=root;
        root=root->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have looks fine. Your initial `temp = root` outside the loop is not necessary since you are not examining `temp` before assigning it again, but of course that won't break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is fine. You might want `delete_list` to take a pointer to the root element as a variable, and you could have written it a little more concisely, e.g.

```
void
delete_list (node *list)
{
    while (list)
    {
        node *tmp = list->next;
        free (list);
        list = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah I like your code better. Thanks!